# MLE of $ \theta$ in $ N(\theta, \theta^2) $ and Asymptotic Distribution of $\hat{{\theta}}_{\text{MLE}}$

Tags: asymptotics, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

**Question** 
Let $( X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n )$ be an independent random sample from $N(\theta, \theta^2)$ where $ \theta \neq 0 $.

Find the MLE for $\theta$ and find the asymptotic distribution of the MLE

**Approach** 
$ L(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n; \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta^2}} \right) \exp\left\{-\frac{(x_i - \theta)^2}{2\theta^2}\right\} 
 = \frac{1}{(\theta \sqrt{2\pi})^n} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\theta^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \theta)^2\right\} $

I know that I need to minimize this function but I'm just not sure how to proceed for this one.

**Leads** 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369417/mle-of-theta-in-n-theta-theta2 
This post provides the following MLE for theta: 
$\hat{{\theta}}_{\text{MLE}} = -\frac{\bar{X}}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2}{n}  + \frac{\bar{X}^2}{4}} $ 
I understood their method but since MLE is not unique and I am not sure how to find the asymptotic distribution here, I am unsure whether I should find another MLE of theta somehow or I'm just being dumb and cannot make out the asymptotic distribution here.

**This is what ChatGPT gave me (supercharged with the Wolfram Plugin):** 
Given the likelihood function:
$ L(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n; \theta) = \frac{1}{(\theta \sqrt{2\pi})^n} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\theta^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \theta)^2\right\} $

The log-likelihood function is:
$ \ell(\theta) = \log L(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n; \theta) $ 
$ \ell(\theta) = -n \log(\theta \sqrt{2\pi}) - \frac{1}{2\theta^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \theta)^2$

Differentiating the log-likelihood with respect to $\theta$:
$\frac{d\ell(\theta)}{d\theta} = -\frac{n}{\theta} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (2\theta - 2x_i)}{2\theta^2} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \theta)^2}{\theta^3}$

The second derivative is:
$\frac{d^2\ell(\theta)}{d\theta^2} = \frac{2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (2\theta - 2x_i)}{\theta^3} - \frac{3 \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i - \theta)^2}{\theta^4}$

The Fisher Information, $I(\theta)$, is:
$I(\theta) = \frac{6n}{\theta^2}$

The asymptotic variance of the MLE is:
$\text{Var}(\hat{\theta}_{\text{MLE}}) \approx \frac{1}{I(\theta)} = \frac{\theta^2}{6n}$

Thus, the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\theta}_{\text{MLE}}$ is:
$ \hat{\theta}_{\text{MLE}} \sim N\left(\theta, \frac{\theta^2}{6n}\right)$

However, I am skeptical of this approach because I have never seen Fischer Information used like this, I thought that it only provides a lower bound for the Variance as per the Cramer-Rao Theorem